# Linq Extension : JoinAndAssign

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm trying to achieve a Linq extension :

```
/// <summary>
/// Perform a join an assign the result into a property of the source
/// </summary>
public static IQueryable<TSource> JoinAndAssign<TSource, TJoined, TKey>
    (   this IQueryable<TSource> querySource
    ,   IQueryable<TJoined> queryJoined
    ,   Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> sourceKeySelector
    ,   Expression<Func<TJoined, TKey>> joinedKeySelector
    ,   Expression<Func<TSource, TJoined>> sourcePropertySelector)
{
    // source =>
    var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TSource), "source");
    // source, joined =>
    var joined = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TJoined), "joined");
    // source => source.Property
    //var propertySelection = Expression.Invoke(sourcePropertySelector, source);
    var member = (MemberExpression) sourcePropertySelector.Body;
    // source => source.Property = joined
    var assignProperty = Expression.Assign(member, joined);

    // well...
    var final = Expression.Block(assignProperty, {..something..})

    // convert to lambda
    var resultSelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TJoined, TSource>>(final, source, joined);

    return
        querySource
            .Join
            (queryJoined
                , sourceKeySelector
                , joinedKeySelector
                , resultSelector
            );
}
```

Honestly I'm not sure I can do it that way, but some constructive insights would be great as I'm no expression tree expert.

**EDIT**

I stepped backward on this extension as it's a play-around to achieve something else. I wrote an explanation of the big picture but it's a novel on itself, and that's not the point of stackoverflow. So I tried another approach to achieve the design I need [in that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741659/composing-expression-trees-for-composite-dto).

Comment: This is a bit hard to understand what you're trying to do: some example objects would help. I'm assuming this is meant to be run against in-memory objects?

Comment: `Expression.Assign` won't work, if you want to translate this into SQL. Also, what do you expect to happen if there is more than one `TJoined` for one `TSource`?

Comment: I think too that Expression.Assign won't work, that seems very logic. However I know some kind of assignation is possible as you can assign when creating a new object. My problem here is that I lack experience in expression tree to do what I want (which is mainly syntactic sugar). I will edit to add information.

Comment: Hard-code the query you want and look at what expression the C# compiler generates for that.